# Referencing integers in an array for completing math operations in objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've made an array in objective C and filled it with a few numbers (I think), and I'm wondering how to reference one of the numbers in the array to complete a pretty basic math problem, but I'm not really sure how to go about doing that.

Here's the array I've created:

```
NSMutableArray *combo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:24], [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:27], nil];
```

This is the math problem I'm trying to create using the array:

```
abs(-1440 - 7.2*[combo objectAtIndex:0])*.01
```

Thank you all for the help in advance! Please let me know if you feel like I'm not being clear enough in what I'm asking

Comment: The value in `NSNumber`s must be extracted by invoking one of its [many accessors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html) before you can treat it like an int.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you need to access the numeric value of the `NSNumber` objects inside the array. So you want to do this:

```
abs(-1440 - 7.2*[[combo objectAtIndex:0] intValue])*.01
```